# How do I re-center nav bar in Twenty Twelve after adding border?

Tags: css, wordpress, navbar

I am working with a Twenty Twelve wordpress child theme and when I add a border to the nav bar, the left edge of the border is aligned with the header image, which pushes the right side over.  How do I center this, extending the border 2px on either side?

This can be seen live at www.valuetactics.com

I tried increasing the header image to 1004px but that had no effect.

Here is my child theme .css

```
    @import url("../twentytwelve.1.6/twentytwelve/style.css");

body.custom-font-enabled {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}


/* Increase theme width to 1000px */
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
    .site {
        max-width: 1000px;
        max-width: 71.4285rem;
    }
}
.ie .site { max-width: 1000px; }

footer[role="contentinfo"] {
    max-width: 1000px;
    max-width: 71.4285rem;
}

/* Left & Right Sidebars */
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .custom-layout .site-content {
        width: 50%;
        margin-left: 25%;
    }
    .custom-layout .widget-area {
        position: relative;
        width: 20%;
    }
    .custom-layout #extra-sidebar {
        float: left;
        margin-left: -75%;
        width: 20%;
    }

}

/* IE8 and IE7 - Left and Right Sidebars */
.ie  .custom-layout .site-content {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 25%;
}
.ie .custom-layout .widget-area {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    position: relative;
}
.ie .custom-layout #extra-sidebar {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -75%;
    width: 20%;
}

/*Ross customizations: */

body .site {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
    margin-bottom: 3.42857rem;
    margin-top: 3.42857rem;
    padding: 0 2.85714rem;
}

.main-navigation {
    margin-top: -65px;
    text-align: center;
}

    .main-navigation ul.nav-menu,
    .main-navigation div.nav-menu > ul {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
        border: 2px solid #C4F4FF;
        border-radius: 4px;
        display: inline-block !important;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
    }

        .main-navigation li a {
        border-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: 20px;
        color: #C4F4FF;
        font-weight:bold; 
        line-height: 3.692307692;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .main-navigation li a:hover,
    .main-navigation li a:focus {
        color: #C4F4FF;
    }

    @import url('../twentytwelve/style.css');

body .headerContent {
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
overflow:visible;
}
body .site {
box-shadow:none;
}

#page {
margin-top:0px;
}

.headerContent, .headerWrapper {
background:#E6E6E6;
}

    .main-navigation ul {
        margin: 0;
    }


    .site-header {
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}


/* Sidebar */
.widget-area .widget {
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: blue;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-top: 1.7rem;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 1.7rem;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background: lightblue;
    }

.header-image {
    margin-top: -3px;
}
```

Here is what it looks like with border: 20px to illustrate the problem a bit more obviously:
http://s22.postimg.org/st72q5fy9/menubarfail.jpg

```
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu,
    .main-navigation div.nav-menu > ul {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
        border: 20px solid #C4F4FF;
        border-radius: 4px;
        display: inline-block !important;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: So, you want the border 2px *outside* the header image? Not sure what you're going for.

Comment: @BrianBennet I linked an image of what it looks like with a 20px border.  The nav bar should be centered on the header image, and the border should extend beyond it.

Comment: no offence man, but that theme looks absolutely terrible. I doubt that adding some kind of border will fix it.

Comment: @MightyPork Thanks for the insight.  Let me know if you need a critique of your next work in progress.

Answer (score 0):

It was an extremely simple fix once I figured it out.  Changed border width to -2 instead of 2.  This brought the border to the inside of the container which allowed it to fit, centered, in the parent.